# SPServiceContext.Current==null

Tags: sharepoint

When I use SPServiceContext.Current to get an object, it just returns null.

I have tried  to give some parameters to SPServiceContext.GetCurrent, such as one SPSite instance, but it still returns null.

Comment: sorry for the mistake, it's SPServiceContext.Current, not SPContext.Current. I just want to do something like "new UserProfileManager(SPServiceContext.Current, ture)".

Comment: Are you running this code from a web page or console/windows app?

Comment: Hi, Ryan, thanks for your reply. I am running this code from a console app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You indicate in your comments that you're running this from a console app.

[SPServiceContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spservicecontext.current.aspx) is the same as GetContext(HttpContext) and can only be used in the context of a **called** web request (i.e. web app running in SharePoint under IIS, not a console app)

From a console app you're probably looking for something like

```
SPSite mySite = new SPSite("Absolute_URL");
SPServiceContext myContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext Method (mySite);
```

See [SPSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.aspx) & [SPServiceContext.GetContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee546948.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There is another possibility here. When I run in a SharePoint custom WCF component in IIS on my development machine which is on a workgroup, then SPServiceContext.Current is always null.

The same code running on a Domain server works fine.

This is actually a major pain as it means that contractors (for example) have to develop as part of a domain which on a travelling laptop is non trivial.